# C++ disable optimization temporarily

Tags: c++, eclipse

How can I disable C++ compiler optimizations temporarily ?
Often need to do this for release builds while debugging. The project settings do help but they need to be changed each time for each project.

For Visual Studio

I tried compiler options in environment variables but the priority is the rightmost conflicting option so Visual Studio overrides any values I set by the project settings.(For eg. /Od set by me in the environment is overridden to /O3 added by the project settings)

For Eclipse

Again modifying the global settings for each project seems to be the only way. Multiple select doesn't show the optimization setting so I am forced edit multiple projects one by one.

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to project settings > C/C++ > optimization

Comment: @NeilKirk I am looking for a single place of control without having to edit projects.

Answer (score 1):

In both VS and Eclipse you can add new build configurations, e.g. an "Unoptimized release" which has all the debug checks in the code removed (via `NDEBUG` macro), but also has optimization disabled for better debugging experience.  This takes a little time to setup, but then switching optimization off is as easy as switching between debug and release build.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Voigt but I am looking for a temporary fix for it. Creating a new configuration and keeping it up-to-date would work, but isn't there a simple environment setting for it?